# Sub-process returned an error code (Solved)

Tags: apt

So suddenly any apt-get command is not working for me anymore. for example when I type in `sudo apt-get upgrade` it outputs

```
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up snapd (2.32.3.2~14.04) ...
Failed to enable unit: Unit file snapd.autoimport.service does not exist.
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

this same problem occurs to me when I type in `apt-get autoremove` `sudo apt-get install -f` and most of the other apt-get commands. What can I actually do, can't find anything that helped me on the internet

So after i tried `sudo apt install --reinstall snapd` this is what it output

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of snapd is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up snapd (2.32.3.2~14.04) ...
Failed to enable unit: Unit file snapd.autoimport.service does not exist.
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

any other solutions?

Comment: do you get the same error with sudo apt upgrade?

Comment: yes, same exact problem

Comment: getting the same error from `sudo -i dpkg --purge --force-all `

Comment: actually I can't run either  and I can't run either `sudo apt-get install <anything>` this thing is getting pretty much annoying

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall snapd`. If it fails, please provide the complete output (edited into your original question)

Comment: still same error. Edited my original post

Answer (score -1):

Add `exit 0` to `/var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.prerm` after `#!/bin/sh`. Then do:

```
dpkg --purge --force-all snapd
sudo apt-get update
```

It seems like, you used older repository to install `snapd` or you upgraded your Ubuntu in not clean way.
So, don't forget to check your `sources.list` for invalid repositories.

Comment: `(Reading database ... 207478 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing snapd (2.32.3.2~14.04) ...
Failed to stop snapd.socket: Unit snapd.socket not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.service: Unit snapd.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd` this is what i get when i  run the `dpkg --purge --force-all  snapd`

Comment: Actually there isn't a line that starts as you said. This is what i get when i open snapd.prerm: `#! /bin/sh

set -e

if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
    systemctl stop snapd.autoimport.service snapd.socket snapd.service
    systemctl disable snapd.autoimport.service snapd.socket snapd.service
fi`

Comment: Check my edited answer, sorry for any inconveniences

Comment: `(Reading database ... 207478 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing snapd (2.32.3.2~14.04) ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed pre-removal script (/var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.prerm): No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd`
This happens

Comment: I think you accidentally removed  `/var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.prerm`. Please post the output of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.prerm`.